# Simple python server which parses POST header/message response

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, http, server

I'm trying to create a simple python server which can parse POST responses sent from a smart hub. It sends data as a HTTP POST (with the appropriate header) and the body as JSON. I'm looking for a way to strip away the header and parse the json body, but I can't quite seem to find anything that's appropriate without resorting to manual parsing.

This is what I have right now. Ideally I'm looking for a library which handles the separating of header/body itself.

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data=conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            ddata = data.decode('utf-8')
            print("Decoded data: %s\n\n\n" % ddata)

            #This doesn't work because it's trying to decode both the header and body, and the header isn't JSON    
            #parsed_data = json.loads(ddata)
            #print("Parsed data: %s\n\n\" % parsed_data)
```

Here's the data I get:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */* User-Agent: Linux UPnP/1.0 Device HOST:
192.168.0.115:8080 Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 17

{"@test_value":8}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should really process the http request properly like a web server does - the header is terminated by a blank line then there is the body (if any).  In fact it may be simpler to use the standard library http server functions. Much simpler, and it will handle the request properly.

Comment: You also need to look at the `Content-Length` in order to know the length of the body instead of trying to read everything. Otherwise your code will just hang waiting for more data. Why don't you just use [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) instead attempting to write your own server?

Comment: Thanks, that's probably much easier, will give it a try